# Populating field with values based on another value using ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, fields-attributes

How do I populate a field y with info1 or Info2 values, depending on the value of the x field, using if conditions?

Comment: What version of ArcGIS and/or Python are you using? e.g. ArcMap 10.x, Python 2.7, or ArcGIS Pro with Python 3.x?

Comment: I don't know if you've seen the ESRI documentation on this, but there are some example field calculations, including python if-then logic at http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/data-management-toolbox/calculate-field-examples.htm#ESRI_SECTION1_11EAB368A53B4D1C9618A58A1B09F9D0  If those don't help you, you may want to click the edit button under your posted question and add some more details including software/version, but also more specifics on what you're having issues with.

Answer (score 1):

The steps will be similar for ArcGIS Pro with Python 3 or ArcMap 10.x, but the code formatting may change (and sometimes, the tool may change between ArcGIS versions). Here's a link to the documentation for ArcMap 10.x's Calculate Field management:

http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/data-management-toolbox/calculate-field.htm

There are a few code examples on that page. Based on your question, I think the third one (below) will be most appropriate.

```
# Name: CalculateField_Ranges.py
# Description: Use CalculateField with a codeblock to calculate values
#  based on ranges

# Import system modules
import arcpy

# Set environment settings
arcpy.env.workspace = "C:/data/airport.gdb"

# Set local variables
inTable = "parcels"
fieldName = "areaclass"
expression = "getClass(float(!SHAPE.area!))"
codeblock = """def getClass(area):
    if area <= 1000:
        return 1
    if area > 1000 and area <= 10000:
        return 2
    else:
        return 3"""

# Execute AddField
arcpy.AddField_management(inTable, fieldName, "SHORT")

# Execute CalculateField 
arcpy.CalculateField_management(inTable, fieldName, expression, "PYTHON_9.3", 
                                codeblock)
```

Some things to keep in mind:

- the codeblock is a multiline string surrounded by triple-quotes
- if you haven't already created the field, you can use AddField_management to create the field before the calculation
- Double-check that your new field is the right data type for the input
- When you are formatting variables that will be used as parameters to the function defined in the codeblock, surround the field (and any methods assigned to the field, such as the area) by exclamation points e.g. `!Shape!` or `!Shape.area!`. Do not surround the parameter in the codeblock with exclamation points, e.g. `def getClass(area)` and `if area <= 1000:`

Comment: Thank you. How about populating the new results to a new column? If column X has value 1, then column Y will have a string value of "Good" else "No". Auto populating from column X to Y.

Comment: Please update your question to include what you've tried. You should just be able to modify the codeblock in my answer above to reflect the if/else condition you just described.

Comment: If you want to test in interactive mode rather than arcpy, use the Field Calculator.